# react-native run-android error without error message

Tags: react-native, command-line-interface

Up to a certain point, everything with react native was working nicely but now when running

```
react-native run-android
```

I get the following "useful" error message:

[image: error]

As you can see there is no 'error above' to be read.

**Q: Is there a way to make the output more verbose so that I can see what the actual problem is?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I did not figure out the reason I still found a solution.

Deleting the ./android folder and running

```
react-native android
```

resolved the problem.

My guess for the reasons:

The project folder came out of a git repo and the ./android folder was already included.
There might have been some information in the configs (java, gradle, whatever) in that folder relating to my coworkers system that did not match my setup.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it would help, but you could try to run the following commands:

```
react-native run-android --stacktrace
```

or

```
react-native run-android --debug
```

Comment: i tried these but they did not result in additional information